# Can't get UpdateAttributeRequest to work

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to use the Metadata Web Service of Dynamics CRM to update the *order* of some picklist options using the **UpdateAttributeRequest** message. Though I get to change the attribute's DisplayName using the **MergeLabels = false** option, the picklist option values themselves seem immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [Order Option Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc156303.aspx)?

```
// Create the request.
OrderOptionRequest orderOptionRequest = new OrderOptionRequest();

// Set the properties for the request
orderOptionRequest.AttributeLogicalName = "address1_addresstypecode";
orderOptionRequest.EntityLogicalName = EntityName.contact.ToString();

// Set the order for the options.
orderOptionRequest.Values = new int[] { 4, 3, 2, 1 };

// Execute the request
OrderOptionResponse orderOptionResponse = (OrderOptionResponse)metadataService.Execute(orderOptionRequest);
```

Comment: There you go! I knew I was missing something. Thanks a lot!